# How to functional test against web services requiring POST data in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have designed a symfony web application that provides restful web services. I would like to write a battery of functional tests that would test these web services that return JSON data.

I am however unsure on how to test for web services that require some test data to be posted to them. That is how do I post some data to a web service URL in my symfony application so that i can assert against some response? By the way I love Symfony as a framework

So here is some sample code that tests for a GET response:

```
 public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/demo/hello/Fabien');

        $this->assertGreaterThan(
            0,
            $crawler->filter('html:contains("Hello Fabien")')->count()
        );
    }
```

What if /demo/hello/Fabien above requires some post data?

many thanks for some insight

Comment: Either your question is unclear, or I can't understand why don't you use `$client->request('POST', '/demo/hello/Fabien');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is the 6th parameter in the request function, so you would do something like this:

```
$data = json_encode(array('name' => 'Fabian'));

$crawler = $client->request(
    'POST',
    '/demo/hello',
    array(),
    array(),
    array(),
    $data
);
```